# I need Javascript help updating the visits number on my webpage to follow the amount of hits on my API

Tags: javascript, html, aws-api-gateway

New to Javascript and need some guidance on this coding. I need help with updating the visits number on my webpage to equal the hits on my api.

When I visit my API URL, it looks like this:

[image]

Website:

[image]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<p style = "text-align: center;">
Visits: <span id="visits">0</span>
</p>

<script>

const countElement = document.getElementById("visits");

function updateVisitCount() {
    fetch('https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Prod')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        countElement.innerHTML = res.value;
    })
}

updateVisitCount();

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Try `= res.hits`. As always, check your browser's console for errors

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've checked the console and it says that it is a CORS error. Now to troubleshoot that..

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Comment: So I fixed the CORS error by using lambda proxy. But now I'm getting:

"Visits: undefined"

on my webpage. Any clue on this?

Comment: See my first comment. Your response has a `hits` property, not `value` so it should be `countElement.innerHTML = res.hits`

Comment: So now that I changed the API with a proxy the API url only displays a number like "95" instead of {"hits":95}

Comment: Why would you do that? If the URL no longer returns JSON, you cannot use `res.json()`. Try `res.text()` instead and perhaps start doing some debugging of your own

Comment: I appreciate the help. It's leading me in the right direction and i'm going to take this info and study it